# Angular 404 redirect

Tags: angularjs

I have a http get request from client angular to server

If the request returns a 404, the app gets redirected to the default page which is my home page.

How do I prevent the redirect on the error function handle therE?

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/customers/' + customer.id + "/addresses", 
      data: address
})
.success(function(address){

})
.error(function(data){
 //prevent the 404 redirect here
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603078/angular-http-404-error-handling