# How to handle a 404 from an API with Angular

Tags: angularjs, rest

As I understand it, the proper REST-ful approach for requesting a resource that doesn't exist is for an API to return a 404.

What is the best way to handle this in Angular so no errors are thrown and nothing shows up in the console log?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603078/angular-http-404-error-handling

Comment: I have implemented interceptors and they appear to be working but I still am seeing errors thrown in the console.

Comment: Are you seeing actual javascript errors or are you just seeing that the request failed in the network tab. If it's the latter, I don't think there is any way to suppress it.