# AngularJS controller not able to access partials data using $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and having a situation to use TABS and I came to below URL and implemented in mine

[Tabs link](http://jsfiddle.net/jccrosby/eRGT8/light/)

only change in the Tabs I implemented with above link is my Tabs data are loaded as partials from server and is not embedded in HTML itself

Initially, when My page loads it renders

```
<div id="tabs" ng-controller="TabsCtrl" >
     //MANY HTML ELEMENTS ARE THERE HERE
     //SOME LINK
</div>

app.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$location,$window,$routeParams) {

   //Below Function is loaded here but actual testConnectivity() button  
   //is present in partials that is going to load in "userSetupTab.html"
   $scope.testConnectivity = function() {
        alert("TEST "+JSON.stringify($scope.userSetupForm));
   };

      //I AM checking here, if TABS LINK is clicked then it calls  
       `url: 'partials/userSetupTab.html'` 
});
```

### userSetupTab.html

```
<form name="userSetupForm" novalidate>
  <table  border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="avLogin-Label" title="Specifies the IP address of the SIP trunk ethernet connection." >PABX IP Address:</label>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="0" >
                    <input class="form-control" title="Specifies the IP address of the SIP trunk ethernet connection." placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"  
                        style="display: inline-block;display:block;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;" type="text" 
                        name="pabxipaddress" id="pabxipaddress" ng-model="userSetup.pabxipaddress" required ng-pattern='pattern' >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="error" ng-show="(testIPOfficeFlag || submitted) && userSetupForm.pabxipaddress.$error.required"><label style="color: red;">Required!</label></span>
                    <span class="error" ng-show='(testIPOfficeFlag || submitted) && userSetupForm.pabxipaddress.$error.pattern'><label style="color: red;">Invalid IP Address!</label></span>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="button" ng-click="testConnectivity()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Test Connection">
                </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Why testConnectivity() function gives me alert as undefined?
is it because `<form name="userSetupForm">` is loaded later and js file is loaded first, I mean to say form is added to controller dynamically through TABS url and that is controller function $scope doesnt know about userSetupForm.

### Actual Need

```
<form>
<ip field> <port field> <userid field> <password field> <test connectivity button>
<first name field>
<last name field>
<submit button>
</form>
```

I have form like above, and validation are done on all fields, but before submitting form, if user wants to try  then it only needs to enter `<ip field> <port field> <userid field> <password field>` and I don't want to validate entire form at that time and only want to validate 4 fields, that is why first I thought of accessing `$scope.userSetup.pabxipaddress.$valid`() then I am getting error as `"Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined"`

it works only when I declare like below in js file

```
 $scope.userSetup= { pabxipaddress: ''}
```

Comment: Actually your $scope does not know anything about your userSetupForm. You can not use 'name = "userSetupForm"' to let the $scope knows about the form. I don't get what you want to achieve when calling testConnectivity function here but I guess you want to test whether the url returns 40 or not. This seems to be quite complex but you can take a look her http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603078/angular-http-404-error-handling. And here is the way how to serialize the data of input http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877212/is-there-a-more-effective-way-to-serialize-a-form-with-angularjs

Comment: @themyth92 `You can not use 'name = "userSetupForm"' to let the $scope knows about the form` - Actually you can.

Comment: If you call `testConnectivity()` before your form is loaded, then you've answered the question yourself.

Comment: @themyth92 see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm (specifically, "Name of the form. If specified, the form controller will be published into related scope, under this name.")